How to extract parameter from url like following
url: http://.../server/:ID([0-9a-fA-F-]+)/resource
Golang can use context.values() to get ":ID". But I am using Java to handle this and fail to find some related questions.
How can I get the ID parameter in Java and what's the style of this URl?

Are you using a library? I think some of the popular libraries like Spring will have tools for this.

There is 2 ways :

Use regex.

For example, you can use the part before and after the ID to find it with regex like server\/(.+?)\/resource :
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("server\/(.+?)\/resource");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}


Split the URL and search on it

You can use myString.split("/"), and then take the right one with split[1] for example, or loop and take the next after server.
